# How to query the Criteo REST API v2 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, jwt, criteo

I want to query the Criteo REST API v2.

The answer below indicates that the REST API v2 has not yet been implement by Criteo so i have used v1 instead. Their website says that v1 will be deprecated soon.

The API v1 is described [here](https://support.criteo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001226125-Testing-Criteo-Marketing-API)

The Swagger for API v1 is [here](https://api.criteo.com/marketing/swagger/ui/index#!/Statistics/Statistics_GetStats)

The REST API v2 which I'd really like to use is [here](https://support.criteo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001265360-Criteo-Resellers-Program-API-Guide-V2-0)

Here is my code at this point:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'jwt'
require 'date'
require 'json'

CLIENT_ID = 'mapi-XXX'

CLIENT_SECRET = 'YYY'

end_date = Date.today

start_date = Date.today - Date.today.mday + 1


# first get a valid token

uri = URI('https://api.criteo.com/marketing/oauth2/token')

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json' }      

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

https.use_ssl = true

https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, headers)

request.set_form_data( 'client_id' => CLIENT_ID, 'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET, 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' )

response = https.request(request)

access_token = JSON.parse(response.body)['access_token']

 puts access_token



uri = URI('https://api.criteo.com/marketing/v1/portfolio')

headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Bearer #{access_token}" }

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

https.use_ssl = true

https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, headers)

response = https.request(request)

puts response.body


uri = URI('https://api.criteo.com/marketing/v1/campaigns?campaignStatus=Running')

headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Bearer #{access_token}" }

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

https.use_ssl = true

https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path, headers)

response = https.request(request)

puts response.body

json = JSON.parse(response.body)

campaigns = json.map { |campaign| campaign['campaignId'] }


# get statistics

puts start_date # => "2018-12-01" 

puts end_date # => "2018-12-17"

uri = URI.parse('https://api.criteo.com/marketing/v1/statistics')

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': "Bearer #{access_token}" }

https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

https.use_ssl = true

https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, headers)

request.set_form_data( 'reportType' => 'CampiagnPerformance', 'ignoreXDevice' => true, 'startDate' => "#{start_date}", 'endDate' => "#{end_date}", 'dimensions' => ['CampaignId'], 'metrics' => ['Clicks'], 'format' => 'Json', 'currency' => 'USD', 'timezone' => 'GMT') 

#request.body = payload.to_json

puts request.body

response = https.request(request)

puts response.body
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to add the following to your `headers`:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer VALID_JWT_TOKEN_BASE64'
```

Also, they don't appear to have migrated their `portfolio` API endpoint to v2 yet.  I was able to resolve their old v1 endpoint ([based on their documentation](https://support.criteo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001226125-Testing-Criteo-Marketing-API)):

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer [token]' https://api.criteo.com/marketing/v1/portfolio
```

That at least gave me an unauthorized response.  Try updating your uri to:

```
uri = URI('https://api.criteo.com/marketing/v1/portfolio')
```

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your suggestion about the auth header and tried a variety of endpoints including your suggestions but no luck.

Comment: @markhorrocks I updated my answer after testing their endpoints.  Looks like they haven't quite made the transition to v2 of their API.

Comment: This is the answer. [Always read the API documentation first](https://api.criteo.com/marketing/swagger/ui/index#!/Portfolio/Portfolio_GetPortfolio) which includes the Request URL `https://api.criteo.com/marketing/v1/portfolio`.

Comment: The question was how to use the REST API v2. I had read the documentation many times but the answer above indicated that v2 is not yet implemented so I resorted to v1 in the interim.